# Communication between View(radio button) and Controller failing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two sets of radio buttons that I must select a option each and then it should fill a "string[] pergunta" in the Controller. But the "string[] pergunta" is always "null". I think the problem maybe is where I should put the id.

```
 @foreach (var pergunta in Model.ls_pergunta)
            {
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="co_pergunta_avaliacao" class="control-label">@pergunta.tx_pergunta</label>
           
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 estrelas" id="pergunta">
       
                            @{
                                    int i = 1;
                                    foreach (var item in @pergunta.ls_opcoes)
                                    {
                                    <label for="cm_star-@item.Value"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-@item.Value" name="pergunta_@pergunta.co_pergunta" value=@item.Value />
                                    i++;
                                    }
                            }
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My controller:

```
 public ActionResult Avaliar(string[] pergunta, int co_atendimento, string tx_observacao)
{
foreach (var item in pergunta)
                    {
                        aactb007_avaliacao_ocorrencia avaliacao = new aactb007_avaliacao_ocorrencia();
                        avaliacao.co_atendimento = co_atendimento;
                        avaliacao.co_pergunta_avaliacao = Convert.ToInt32(item.Split('_')[0]);
                        avaliacao.co_parametro = Convert.ToInt32(item.Split('_')[1]);

                        db.aactb007_avaliacao_ocorrencia.Add(avaliacao);

                    }

                    var usuario_sys = Usuario.logado.Co_usuario;
                    //var usuario_sys = Environment.UserName;

                    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/aspnet-wire-format-for-model-binding-to-arrays-lists-collections-dictionaries

Comment: Helped me a lot again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the name. So I changed to name="pergunta[i]" and worked.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in @pergunta.ls_opcoes)
{
    <label for="cm_star-@item.Value"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-@item.Value" name="pergunta[i]" value=@item.Value />
    i++;
}
```